# How to update global variable inside a function and use outside a function in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a function as defined below, here `$scope.questions` is a global variable. I want to modify the global variable like `$scope.questions.push("asdsd");`

```
$scope.viewQuestion = function(item) {
        //$scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
console.log(item);
        //$scope.questions.push(item);
        $scope.questions.push("asdsd");
        console.log($scope.questions);
        //$cookieStore.put('question', $scope.questions);

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'questionbank.view.html',
            controller: 'questionbankController',
            //$scope.products = products;
            //size: size,
            resolve: {
                user: function() {
                    return item;
                },
                products: function () {
                    //console.log($scope.selectedProducts);
                    return item; // get all available products
                }
            }
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItems) {
            //products = selectedItems;
        }, function () {

            $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());


        });

  };
```

I want to console out the updated global variable value outside the function.

Comment: Just a note on naming: `$scope.questions` is not a global variable as it is usually described. It's merely a property on the `$scope`, which itself is injected into the directive, controller, whatever. Global variables are generally defined as variables which exist on the global scope, which for browsers is the `window` object.

Answer (score 0):

You update it when you use $scope.questions.push("asdsd");. The problem is more that you don't see it on the console because your console.log is call only once at the first execution. So you have to watch the change of the value for that :

```
  $scope.$watch(function ($scope) {
                return $scope.questions;
            }, function(newValue){ 
                 console.log(newValue); 
             }, true);
```